# Rounding by 5 minute interval

Tags: shell, date

How do I round it to the next 5th interval?

```
# date
Sat Oct 13 22:09:25 IST 2012
# date '+%H-%M'
22-09

the output should be
22-10
```

When the minute is 58 it should round to 00 and not 60 though.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak this:

```
date '+%H-%M' | awk -F- '{ while( $2 % 5 != 0 ){ $2++ }; print $1, $2 % 60 }'
```

Example:

```
$ date '+%H-%M' | awk -F- '{ while( $2 % 5 != 0 ){ $2++ }; print $1, $2 % 60 }'
18 55
```

How it works:

- Split the time over a hyphen
- Increment the minute until it divides 5
- Output the result with the minute modulo 60, so 60 -> 0.

Comment: Great solution! Just remember to handle rollovers.

Comment: The question isn't too clear for me, I thought the user wanted 11:56 -> 11:00 though that's probably not very practical. It'll leave adding one to `$1` (`% 24`) as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: Close. But I am not able to round 45-49 to 50 and 05-59 should become 06-00 and not 05 0

Comment: Yes, that's because I didn't give you a full solution, only a very large pointer as to how I'd do it.